# Is it possible to call native ios Facebook login dialog from just a web page (not a web app)?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, safari

We have an ios app that uses native Facebook login just fine.

Then we also have a website (app is basically an optimized client for it) where people can login via Facebook too. When they open our website in mobile safari, they are directed to Facebook pages to authenticate there and it works, but.. it is still far from native and users have to retype credentials they often have in ios already.

So could it be possible to to somehow launch system fb authentication for just a web page (maybe using some clever URL schema?) and get granted token back to web?

Comment: You can use the token acquired by your mobile app on your server side (so they don't need to log in at all if they've already logged in via your mobile app).

Comment: Hmm, how can mobile safari identify itself as the same user we have in app then? :/

Comment: What does your website do that needs authentication? Does it make graph API requests? If so, it can use the same access token you got from the mobile app.

Comment: Well, it just uses facebook as one of the signup-login methods. We surely can use the same fb token in the webview shown within the app, but I don't get how you can put it into a stand-alone mobile safari.

Comment: @Artem have you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, Luigi and I by now don't think there is one. It would need an explicit iOS support and I asked this question hoping that one exists. But apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe @Artem you must investigate on iOS SDK to decode comportment and replace it

Comment: I'm thinking like @ValerieLinc

Answer (score 5):

**Difficult way**
As described here http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#mobile-apps you could find URL scheme to trigger the native iOS app for app authorization:

```
fbauth://authorize?redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]&client_id=[client_id]&response_type=token
```

But if you call that link it's not possible to have a redirection. You could try to hack that redirection but maybe you could not find a way out.

A **secure way** to solve that problem is to use a SSO token to authenticate user on your App when he logs in, and next on Safari take a redirection, with a custom url to your APP, that do as bridge to FB App via Token stored in your APP. After FB authentication you can directly redirect user back to your landing page in Safari. As said by @Lego it's an alternative way to direct authenticate that could be made by going deep to custom URL used by FB.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, Nanako!

Certainly only for people who do have our own app installed, but hey, that's one more reason to install it :)

Then I wonder if it is possible to check from web page's javascript if there is a handler for myapp:// present in the system.. probably it's not possible to check, but maybe we could fire two Javascript requests: one to myapp:// and another one to perform a web login. myapp:// will just override.

Comment: It seems whatever URL I set the redirect_uri to, I get a white page in what appears to be a UIWebView in the Facebook app.

Comment: Have you find a solution on redirect?

Comment: i have the app, loading my website in a web-view. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not yet possible to directly authenticate the user via the native Facebook App, but it's possible to authenticate the user using a custom URL scheme which opens your native iOS app which then handles the authentication flow:

1. The user authenticates natively with your iOS App. You then store the user login (**not** password) in your app (i.e. using `NSUserDefaults`).
2. Then the user opens your web page in Mobile Safari. You redirect the user via a custom url scheme to your app (i.e. using myapp://authenticate). Apple documentation on implementing custom URL schemes: [click](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50)
3. Now, if you have an active FB session in your iOS app, you can either directly redirect the user back to your landing page in Mobile Safari, passing the access token via url get parameter or you first re-authenticate the user, displaying a login view with the user name pre-filled, which you have stored in your iOS app before (step 1) and then redirect the user to your landing page, again all depending on session state and your security needs.

Comment: question is talking about to direct authenticate user with FB app (Safari->FB App->Safari) not via user App (Safari -> UserApp -> FB app -> Safari). Maybe that answer it's not that we are looking for.

Comment: @LuigiSaggese Right. Just wanted to provide an alternative approach instead of just answering with a "no, it's not possible". I've updated my answer, to make myself clear.

Comment: I have added a possible solution but we must go deep to find a work around to redirection problem.

Comment: Nice question. That's a great alternative lego. I wonder if you can use the same FB app token with safari.

Comment: @Sha Yes, you can. **Tokens are portable**. FB docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

For opening face book app you can use Custom URL scheme. But i am  not sure if u can authenticate user from it. In case if you could also then it will be confined up to the fb account which is already configured on that device app .so better try to use face book api or something

Answer (score -1):

I don't get your question exactly but i think as per your question you want to create fb app Login in safari or in your custom web view.

is this perfect ?

as per my knowledge web view is different thing and native app is different thing.

if you are Login in web view then no need to check anything token or other thing because it will give you Logout thing there.

but if you are Login in your application then "developer.facebook.com" will definitely help you.
and yes, you will do most of the thing in your app as native facebook app do.

Hope it help....